# How do I loop this statement until a user enters 2012?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class whileLoopOlympics
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println ("Which year was the most recent London Olympics?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
    String yearAsString = scanner.nextLine();
    int year = Integer.parseInt(yearAsString);


    while (year!=2012)
    {
        System.out.println ("Which year was the most recent London Olympics?");
        Scanner next = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yearAsString2 = scanner.nextLine();
        int year1 = Integer.parseInt(yearAsString2);

}
}
}
```

I'm trying to loop until the user inputs 2012 however I can't figure out how to do something such as while (year!= 2012 && year1!=2012) I just don't understand how to do this when "year" isn't in the while loop

Comment: Don't do this twice with `year` and `year1`.  Just implement your loop to read the input into `year`.  Before the loop, initialize `year` to `null`.  And then just loop while `year != 2012`.

Comment: you could switch your `while(...)` loop to a `do{...}while(...)`

Comment: Use break statement !!!

Comment: Like this:- `while(true) { read input; if input == 2012 then break;}`

Comment: Why declare a new variable `year1`? Just assign new value to `year`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create new scanner and new variables, you can reuse.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class whileLoopOlympics
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int year = 0;


    while (year!=2012)
    {
        System.out.println ("Which year was the most recent London Olympics?");
        String yearAsString = scanner.nextLine();
        year = Integer.parseInt(yearAsString);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you'd get a NumberFormatException if the user enters something that is not an int, just saying

Comment: @ochi - the OP's posted code has that same issue.  This answer didn't introduce that as a bug, it simply addresses the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class whileLoopOlympics
{
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int year = 0;
    Scanner next = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (year!=2012) {
        System.out.println ("Which year was the most recent London Olympics?");  
        String yearAsString = scanner.nextLine();
        year = Integer.parseInt(yearAsString2);

    }
}
```

Try this

Comment: you'd get a NumberFormatException if the user enters something that is not an int, just saying

Answer (score 0):

To summarize some ideas I saw in the comments with my own :

You shall try not to repeat your code this often. You don't have to use this many variables and scanners (you even declare some that you're **never** using).

```
// Do not declare a new scanner for any line you read
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
// If you're as maniac as I am, you can use only ONE string as well (or even no String...)
String user_input;
int year = 0;

while (year != 2012)
{
    System.out.println ("Which year was the most recent London Olympics?");
    user_input = scan.nextLine();
    year = Integer.parseInt(yearAsString2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd change it to a `do/while`

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int year = -1;

        do{
            System.out.println ("Which year was the most recent London Olympics?");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String yearAsString = scanner.nextLine();

            try{
                year = Integer.parseInt(yearAsString);

            }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                System.out.println ("Invalid year; numbers only please");
            }
        }while (year != 2012 );
        System.out.println ("Correct! Thanks");
    }
```

Comment: I didn't down voted but this loop will execute when we get 2012 also

Comment: 1. you did not explicitly say what the problem was; instead you just fixed it in the code; 2. you suggested a different approach that's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @mre completely unnecessary? please explain - the code executes once (at least once) just like the initial code, explanation was forthcoming but the OP already chose an answer... IMHO, this is a better approach as it reduces code duplications (hence the refactoring)

Comment: @Devavrata in all cases the code needs to prompt at least once, right? (to obtain the input from user)

Comment: 1. answer the question; 2. provide an alternate approach, if necessary. opinion based answers aren't valuable IMHO. this is just feedback..not a personal attack.

Comment: @mre meh! that's your opinion... equally non-valuable - I've seen plenty of alternate methods of answering questions here (will not bother with examples, you've seen them too...  ridiculous!!!)